# How can I get the middle value of a shell command in bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash shell script. In there, I execute a command and save the output to a variable. The value is like this:

```
0x34f0020d4         4 0x434346000 test_string
```

How can I parse and save the value of the 3rd string (i.e. 0x434346000), assume the value is separated by space or tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
var=$(echo "$string" | awk '{ print $3 }')
```

Test:

```
echo "$var"
```

Results:

```
0x434346000
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your command which gives the above output in this fashion:

```
x=($(your command))
$ echo ${x[2]}
0x434346000
```

The output of the command is being stored in an array "x", and hence the index 2 of the array contains the 3rd element.

Answer (score 3):

Use the shell `read` command:

```
read first second third rest <<< "$line"
echo $third
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the cut command.
echo "axbxc" | cut -f 2 -d "x" gives b

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to index values:

```
arr=("0x34f0020d4         4 0x434346000 test_string")
echo "${arr[2]}"
```